# Git operations from command line adding 'www.' and '.com' to remote url

Tags: git, tfs

I have a situation where git operations from the command line client are changing the remote url from

`http://{servername}:{portnumber}/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/{repositoryname}`

to

`http://www.{servername}.com/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/{repositoryname}`

For example:

Commands like `git remote show origin` or `git push origin` (actually, `git clone http://{servername}:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/obs` produces the same thing, it's just that I'm trying to push an existing repo), results in
`fatal: unable to access 'HTTP://www.{servername}.com/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/obs': The requested URL returned error: 503`

Does anyone have any ideas how to address this?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Is there a HTTP redirect occurring on the server?

Comment: It is possible that there is a redirect, but I tried setting http.allowRedirect=false and that didn't change anything so figured I'd ask on SO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error info:

> The requested URL returned error: 503

This issue usually related to proxy setting up. If you have an environment variable for a proxy it will override git proxy settings. Please give a try after removing the proxy.